# Multiple definitions of main with Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, multiple-definition-error

I am trying to compile my C++ program using `make` and I've come across this problem that I can't quite understand. I have 3 files in the `src` folder of my project: `App.h`, `App.cpp` and `main.cpp`. I have my Makefile located in the root folder of my project, which has the `src` folder that I mentioned in it. This is what my Makefile looks like:

```
CC=g++
SRCDIR=./src
CFLAGS=-I$(SRCDIR)
LIBS=-lSDL -lGL
_DEPS=App.h
DEPS=$(patsubst %,$(SRCDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))
_OBJ=main.o App.o
OBJ=$(patsubst %,$(SRCDIR)/%,$(_OBJ))
_SRC=main.cpp App.cpp
SRC=$(patsubst %,$(SRCDIR)/%,$(_SRC))

%.o: $(SRC) $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

tetris: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(SRCDIR)/*.o $(SRCDIR)/*~
```

When I type `make` into the terminal to compile, I get an error like this:

```
g++ -c -o src/main.o src/main.cpp -I./src
g++ -c -o src/App.o src/main.cpp -I./src
g++ -o tetris src/main.o src/App.o -I./src -lSDL -lGL
src/App.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
src/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
src/main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `App::App()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `App::onExecute()'
src/App.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `App::App()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `App::onExecute()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But I am sure that I only have 1 main function, and it is in the `main.cpp` file. What is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at these lines:

```
src/main.o: In function `main':
src/App.o: In function `main':
```

Those mean that `main` is defined both in `main.o` and `App.o`.

And above those:

```
g++ -c -o src/main.o src/main.cpp -I./src
g++ -c -o src/App.o src/main.cpp -I./src
```

See? Both object files are built using the same source!

You probably want to change this line for the object dependency:

```
%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at the compilation lines.

You are compiling `main.cpp` as both `main.o` and `App.o`.

You are listing **all** your source files as prerequisites of the `%.o` pattern and using `$<` to only compile the first one (which happens to be `main.cpp` in this case.

You want `%.c` instead of `$(SRC)` there.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I had to accept rodrigo's answer since he was the first to answer